# jQuery active state

Tags: jquery, toggle, show-hide

I am trying to set up a simple toggle but want the active state not to be clickable and hide other items.

I have a basic example working:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.entry-title').click(function() {
        $(".entry-content").hide("normal");
        $(this).closest('.post').find('.entry-content').fadeIn();
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

I tried if statment but with no luck.

```
$(".entry-title").click(function() {

    if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {

        $(this).removeClass('active');
        $(this).closest('.post').find('.entry-content').fadeIn();

    } else {
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $(".entry-content").hide("normal");
    }
    return false;
});
```

I know there must be a simplier way but my brain ain't working.

Any help is much appreciated.